# Any way to get root without a custom recovery? (Unlocked bootloader)

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, bootloader, motorola

I have a phone with an unlocked bootloader (Motorola Moto Maxx XT1225) but there's no custom recovery available for it yet.

Is there any way to get root/flash super su without a custom recovery?

Or any way to modify stock recovery to be able to flash unsigned zips?

**edit:** device is on 4.4.4, it's the "international" version of Droid Turbo, just released device.

**edit2:** this is not droid maxx. It's moto maxx, Released 2014 November: http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=5604&idPhone2=6779